# Firebase rules: How to access document id when querying collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am stuck with this one and need help please

I have a firebase document like so:

```
"789" : { 
    slug: "document-slug-name",
    owner_uid: "123",
}
```

which has a subcollection called "roles" that looks like this:

```
"345" : {
    permission_type: 1,
}
```

Now I am querying the documents like this:

```
const snapshot = await firebaseApp.firestore()
    .collection("documents")
    .where("owner_uid", "==","123")
    .where("slug", "==", "document-slug-name")
    .limit(1)
    .get()

const document = snapshot.docs[0]
```

my rules look like this:

```
match /documents/{documentId} {
  allow list: if
    get(/databases/$(database)/documents/documents/$(documentId)/roles/$(currentUser().uid)).permission_type == 1;
}
```

But for some reason, both the rules simulator and the actual firebase db tell me that documentId is not set?

I have also tried resource.data.uid and resource.id to get the documents id but both are not set :(

is there any other way to query the roles subcollection?

Comment: Welcome on SO @Natarius! I can see how the query has been created, however we do not know how it has been used to get the object. Can you add some code? It would be nice as well to tag which language you have used...I am guessing this is JS...

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes, this is JS. Added some more code on how I am using the query...let me know if its enough

Comment: I am not sure, but this does not seem to be proper this double `documents` in the `get`? shouldn't it be once?

Comment: the root namespace for collections in FB is "/databases/$(database)/documents"

and my example collection is called "documents"

therefore the path is "/databases/$(database)/documents/documents"